# is something contradictory means it is wrong?

Tags: logic

there are a lot of daily social activity of human civilization actually contradictory, or it has no direct logical reasoning to support such operation.

for example 
1. talking to someone that you don't really want to know about
2. emotional context
3. stock market trend

i want to ask if "contradiction = wrong" is because we lack of knowledge to find the reason for the contradicted thing? or something is definitely contradictory in any state of affair?

if the answer is first  (contradiction = lack of knowledge to find the reason of it), is that means we are asserting we have not enough knowledge when we asserting other arguments have contradiction (or both of people are lack of knowledge when the owner of the argument also cannot provide the logical proof)

if the answer is second (something is definitely contradictory in any state of affair), is such thing can be defined as the contradiction of truth ( thus we found the truth by reversing it)?

thanks.

Comment: What's contradictory about your examples?

Comment: such as the anger made us act irrationally. stock market flowing is not exactly bases on the circumstance of the actual revenue of the company, anticipating something that usually will not happen at all

Comment: Two statements are *contradictory* when one is the *denial* of the other.

Comment: A statement is called a *contradiction* when it implies (or it is itself) a couple of contradictory statements.

Comment: Thus, a contradiction is a *false* statement (at least in "classical" two-valued logic), because two contradictory statements cannot both be true simultaneously.

Comment: Having said that, "contradictory" is a property of statements and not of "activities", "operations" or "states of affair". Specifically, the "standard" view of semantics is that *reality* is **not** contradictory: the basic postulate of semantical interpretation is that a (set of) statement is *consistent* (i.e. **not** contradictory) if and only if it has a "model", i.e. there is a "state of affair" that *realizes* the (set of) statement.

Comment: I think what you're describing is simply that some motivators to our actions contradict the objectives of others. Our motivators are not designed to be complementary and often contradict one another, that is why most signals are passed by the cerebral cortex before being translated to action, so that a logical choice can be made as to which contradictory objective to follow.

Comment: You have to be careful when presuming motive. I doubt stock market traders act solely to maximise profits, they will be motivated by desire for social recognition, avoidance of cognitive dissonance etc their actions may well be a rational method to satisfy these objectives.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in studying the position of Dialetheism.  You can read about it on the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/

It deals with the theory that there are true contradictions and discards the law of non-contradiction in a general sense.  This isn't to say that there can't be any contradictions, as far as I understand it, but that A and -A does not entail absurdity for every possible A.  You can find a better, more accurate description at the link I posted.  I'm not sure if it will answer the question that you posted, but if you're interested in pursuing the implications of accepting certain contradictions, you may find this resource helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about isn't actually a contradiction; it's called "laterality".

First, validity does not mean that something is true; only that it logically follows from causation to conclusion. If the causation (what starts the thing happening) is not true, then the logic can still follow to the conclusion for validity--but it will always be false. This is used often in storytelling to establish a logical basis for things that don't actually exist--how a person would react, for example, if elves came out from under the east end of the Brooklyn Bridge and claimed to have been there the whole time.

Laterality is the acceptance of logical following without asserting whether or not something is true.

Now, if we consider the causation indisputable, we can still have two (or more, but for simplicity let's stick to two) different ways of seeing the way that things played out.

Person A thinks that the stock market's influences are entirely based in reasoning and perception about how people are going to react.

Person B thinks that the stock market's influences are entirely based in reactivity and don't really take reason into account.

Neither of these people is necessarily right or wrong, and aren't necessarily true or false; they merely see two different perspectives which can both be considered valid. If they want to argue over which is better reasoning, great. If they want to argue over which is more true, that could actually cause problems, since it's not provably true or false--it's just two opinions which are laterally valid.

I hope that helps clarify!

Comment: for your case you gave out two statements, which is person A and person B. and you assumed that two opinions which are laterally valid. however these 2 statements looks contradicted each others (by ~reasoning and reasoning relationship). in this case, how can these 2 statements be true together. is that just your example which is not completed to elaborate the entire scenario?

Comment: in this case, even through afterwards you gave out a better statement ( which is two statements and looks no more contradiction included), is it really 100% guarantee they will not contain any logical fallacy anymore? or issues created after the change of the state of affairs? or there is something which is 100% free from logical fallacy? any example for it?

Comment: in case something will be asserted from true to false after the changes of state of affairs (or placing both statement in the same statement but they are consider correct separately)? what is called "fact" when we consider something in the actual world (is it true or false?)? or in fact everything is just either true or false, our knowledge is some description of the empirical experience reflection of us without reasoning?

Comment: Lateral validity can often be contradictory; but that doesn't necessarily make one right and the other wrong, which was the question.